# how to define odometer for invidual turtlebots?

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in a simulation where multiple turtlebots are employed, can each turtlebot have individual odometer??? Although i can see the odometry information in gazebo by clicking on individual robots, i need the information inside my program...(i'm using hydro)
thanking you....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207015/how-to-define-odometer-for-invidual-turtlebots??/) by [atis](https://answers.ros.org/users/22129/atis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must push down the nodes publishing odometry data into their own namespaces.

It sounds to me that you have two turtlebots. Let's call them turtle1 and turtle2. They are both publishing odometry data to the same topic. Let's call that topic "odom" in the global namespace /odom. What you want is each turtlebot to publish on that topic in its own namespace. /turtle1/odom and /turtle2/odom, respectively.

So in your launch file do something to the effect of:

```
 <node ns="turtle1" name="odom_pub_turtle1" pkg="your_package" type="your_node" />
 <node ns="turtle2" name="odom_pub_turtle1" pkg="your_package" type="your_node" />
```

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0